# Side By Side Editors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor

I was wondering if it's possible to have two editors open all the time. 
The first one should open Java files and the second one XML files.

So if I decide to open a file from the package explorer and it's *Java, it will automatically be opened in the first editor, if it's an XML, it will be opened in the second one.

So far I use 'Window/new editor' from the menu bar to do that, then I drag the files to the right editor.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get auto-open by file type to the left vs. right window.

Also, you don't need to use ***Window-NewWindow***.

Just drag the tab of an opened file to the ***left margin*** and Eclipse will open 
 a new window and move the dragged file to the new window.  The newly opened
 window will auto-close when you close the last file contained within.